# Words finder regex fails

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using this pattern to check if certain words exists in a string:

```
/\b(apple|ball|cat)\b/i
```

It works on this string `cat ball apple`

but not on `no spaces catball smallapple`

How can the pattern be modified so that the words match even if they are combined with other words and even if there are no spaces?

Comment: Remove the \b. It means word-boundry. That's exactly what you don't need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `\b` from the regex. `\b` will match a word boundary, and you want to match the string that is not a complete word.

You can also remove the capturing group (denoted by `()`) as it is not required any longer.

Use

```
/apple|ball|cat/i
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xU9gP6/2)

An [IDEONE PHP demo](https://ideone.com/OQmuxP):

```
$re = "/apple|ball|cat/i"; 
$str = "no spaces catball smallapple";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Results:

```
[0] => cat
[1] => ball
[2] => apple
```

Comment: I'd also remove the capturing group - it is no longer necessary.